# WP-e-commerce (getshopped) Hebrew language files - where can I get them?

Tags: e-commerce, multi-language, plugin-wp-e-commerce, translation, plugin-wpml

I’m working on a dual language website (english+hebrew) the website uses wpml+wpec.
I’m looking for the hebrew language files (mo/po) – where can i get them?

Answer (score 1):

host there own GlotPress which has most of the strings translated to Hebrew at
http://languages.getshopped.org/projects/wp-e-commerce/he/default

and you can always contribute the rest :)

Comment: Hey Bainternet! thanks for your answer. I already have about 70% of the translation files, but i don't want to keep it to myself - I want to contribute. However, it seems as if the wpec glotpress hebrew page is not being managed, no one approves translated terms etc... how can i move on with that? i tried contacting wpec team via the forums and got no reply...

Comment: if you tried contacting them and still no replay I'm sure that others would love if you share your translation, try the Hebrew WordPress Facebook group  http://www.facebook.com/groups/wordpress.support/